# How do the dependency paths work in Java .classpath file?

Tags: java, classpath

In the Java .classpath file, I see a lot of dependency paths, something like this:

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/a/b/c/d/library.jar"/>
```

Are these paths absolute to local file system, or are they relative to some project folders?

Without using tools like Maven, how can multiple developers work on the same project sharing the same .classpath if they have different dependency repo location? If different developers of the same project work on different OS, like Windows and Linux, would these paths still work? Say for windows, can I have a path absolute to my file system (e.g. C:\my_repo...)? Would that break something for the Linux developers if we share the same .classpath file?

And if I pass the project to someone else to continue to work on, how can that person get those dependency jar files back on their local repo without downloading those jars one by one manually from the Internet/Maven central? (Without using Maven, that is...)

Comment: This is not a "Java .classpath file", it is most likely an Eclipse classpath file for a Java project. It is specific to Eclipse. As I recall it is possible to use variables in the file to make them more portable, but I have not had to do that for more than ten years. Everyone should use Maven or Gradle by now. Manual builds are outdated.

Comment: @ewramner You’re right about the file, of course.  But I vehemently disagree with your claim that only Maven or Gradle is suitable for building.  Dependencies are an expensive penalty, which those tools portray as trivial.  And that’s just one issue with them.

Comment: Well, you are entitled to your view and I agree about the dependency problem, but Maven and Gradle both solve the "get those jar files without downloading one by one" problem and any other tool that solves that problem will have the same side effect - dependencies become easy to add as there is no manual labor required to get them. The solution in the bad old days (with Ant or make files) was to check in the jar files as part of the project, perhaps in a thirdparty directory. Then all developers get them from there. You could try that.